# SIP Content-Type charset, in which standard is it defined

Tags: sip

Section [20.15](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-20.15) of RFC 3261 mentions the `Content-Type` as:

> The Content-Type header field indicates the media type of the
> message-body sent to the recipient.  The "media-type" element is
> defined in [H3.7].  The Content-Type header field MUST be present if
> the body is not empty.  If the body is empty, and a Content-Type
> header field is present, it indicates that the body of the specific
> type has zero length (for example, an empty audio file).

> The compact form of the header field is c.

> Examples:

> ```
>  Content-Type: application/sdp
>  c: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4
> ```

My question: where is `charset` defined, and are there any predefined values?

All I found in RFC 3261 was in section [25.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-25.1) defines the syntactical form (vai ABNF) for `Content-Type` as:

> message-header  =  (Accept
> ...
> /  Content-Type
> ...

> Content-Type     =  ( "Content-Type" / "c" ) HCOLON media-type

> media-type       =  m-type SLASH m-subtype *(SEMI m-parameter)

> m-type           =  discrete-type / composite-type

> discrete-type    =  "text" / "image" / "audio" / "video"                   / "application" / extension-token

> composite-type   =  "message" / "multipart" / extension-token

> extension-token  =  ietf-token / x-token

> ietf-token       =  token

> x-token          =  "x-" token

> m-subtype        =  extension-token / iana-token

> iana-token       =  token

> m-parameter      =  m-attribute EQUAL m-value

> m-attribute      =  token

> m-value          =  token / quoted-string

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SIP, the Content-Type header is defined as a MIME type and as such inherit of MIME character sets handling . So in theory you should pick the registered values on IANA : [IANA charsets](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml)

The details of registration are defined `IANA Charset Registration Procedures` [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2978)